Cómo puedo extraer los caracteres en posición par de una cadena en XSLT?
tengo generado un número y quiero mediante xslt sacar por un lado los caracteres que se encuentren en una posicion par, y por otro los que se encuentren en una impar. Por ejemplo, si mi xml de entrada es
<entrada>
    <cadena>123456789</cadena>
</entrada>
quiero que mi xsl me devuelva algo como
<PAR>2468</PAR>
<IMPAR/>13579<IMPAR>
Gracias!


Sabes que la versión actual de XSLT es 3.0? Utilizando XSLT 3.0 es fácil solucionarlo:
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="cadena">
    <xsl:variable name="characters" select="(. => string-to-codepoints()) ! codepoints-to-string(.)"/>
    <PAR>{$characters[xs:integer(.) mod 2 = 0]}</PAR>
    <IMPAR>{$characters[xs:integer(.) mod 2 = 1]}</IMPAR>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

Ejemplo en línea (utilizando XSLT 3.0 con SaxonJS directamente en el navegador).
En la mayoría de las plataformas, la implementación integrada solo apoya XSLT 1.0 pero para XSLT 3.0 puedes utilizar Saxon HE 11 o 12 para Java, Saxon.NET 10 para .NET framework o SaxonC 12 HE para Python o SaxonJS 2.6 para JavaScript o Node.js.
